# Is it possible to read and concatenate unique hardarwe ID of STM32F429ZI microcontroller connecting with any of the Hardarwe which has unique ID?

Tags: c, concatenation, stm32f4, hardware-id

I Need to read the unique ID from the STM32F429 microcontroller and also  read the ID from any of the  Hardware device by connecting it to STM32F microcontroller(eg- sensors or any device which has unique ID and compatible with STM microcontroller) at the same time and then concatenate these two IDs and then encrypt the concatenated ID by using any of the encryption algorithm.

but as of now I am trying to read the STM32F429 microcontroller unique, but is it possible to concatenate the ID of microcontroller with any of the Hardware device which as unique ID in it and reading them in a single script?? If it is possible to do so kindly suggest me which Hardware device would be better to consider and as unique ID which can be read along  with STM32F429 nucleo-144 microcontroller board.

Comment: what is Computer Hardware ID ? Is it your PC, server you store the data, or your smartwatch.

Comment: @P__J__  It is my PC. When researched on this Topic I got to know that each PC has a unique Hardware ID which can be read. So i Need to concatenate my PC ID and the STM32F microcontroller Id